# Emoticons, am I the first?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should smilies be turned into images in questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/636/should-smilies-be-turned-into-images-in-questions-and-answers)

It just struck me that we need emoticons. So often I find myself typing `;)` and then wondering how to format it so it looks right. In the edit box, it looks fine, and I guess the backstrophe has been perfected so it looks right. But still the basic emoticons would be nice. And can't we have something creative, StackOverflow-ish, instead of the standard ones that we see in forums? I really like the ones Skype uses. A few that we should have are `:)`, `;)`,`:/`, `:(`, `:O`, plus a few others I probably missed.

Oh, and no emoticons in code blocks.

Comment: No please, they remember me the fishy free smileycons programs that I usually find on my relatives pc (when I have to fix them)

Comment: No, you're not the first.

Comment: Last stop before animated avatars. ☹

Comment: You're [not the first](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/636/should-smilies-be-turned-into-images-in-questions-and-answers), and you won't be the last, but you'll get the same response: **NO!**

Comment: <insert rchern-backwards-smiley joke here>

Comment: This is what I think about this question:  **ఠ_ఠ**

Answer (score 14):

## No

The world is a better place when not riddled with misshapen circles meant to represent emotion. If you *really really really* need them just use the ASCII alternatives that you listed.

Comment: That "No" is not really large enough. No, really... there is no font large *enough*.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest that we format `:)` as:

And we can use the same algorithm for many others, including but not limited to the ones you've listed. The possibilities are endless!

Comment: This applies to questions and answers only, of course. Comments are exempt.

Comment: I don't understand. What are we formatting as what?

Comment: @Tshepang: Naturally!

Comment: @tshepang: `whoosh` (sorry, but it's true)

Comment: Is this a humor post?

Comment: @Tshepang: Yes. You can tell because it has an emoticon in it.

Comment: I must consume my humor-detection vitamins more consistently.