# Do we want emojis in posts?

Tags: discussion, markdown, emoji

I am looking for a canonical question and answer on this issue.

[This question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18079/how-do-i-make-my-cat-accept-the-new-vacuum-robot) (*see [edit history](https://pets.stackexchange.com/posts/18079/revisions)*) on [Pets.se](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) has prompted me to ask this question.

> [image]

In all honesty I think we just don't need a comic strip to explain what a user is saying. Currently I edit out emoticons I see, but this post presents a whole new type of .... ? what I'm not sure.

Is there are community consensus on this either way?

These questions are related — but different:

- *[Should smilies be turned into images in questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/636/should-smilies-be-turned-into-images-in-questions-and-answers)*
- *[Emoticons, am I the first?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77958/emoticons-am-i-the-first)*
- *[Support Emoji in Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260622/support-emoji-in-markdown)*

Please try and answer sensibly (*rolls eyes at the prospect of a flood of emojis in answers*) — so we can actually have something that we can link to new users (or old users) when editing this stuff out — or (*even worse*), defending its existence.

Comment: IMO, it's not different from other noise like "thanks", "I am 24 years old from Springfield", etc. Just edit it out, and if asked say it's noise. Posts should be focused on the question/answer only, without background noises.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd care to write an answer - that we can get upvoted and purge this plague before it goes viral?

Comment: No time now, will do when having time and if nobody else will do it. :-)

Comment: No, please, absolutely not. 

Comment: @JohnMiliter aha!!! I knew it would happen :)

Comment: Should a thing be allowed here which should have never been allowed into the Unicode? Hmm that's a hard question…

Comment: How is "rolls eyes at ..." better than the succinct " at...?" Personally, I think there would be much less hostility if I could display my intentions via emoji. Perhaps this is unique to me, but there have been times I've wanted to leave SE altogether because of galling comments. On one specific occasion I know I read the sentence different from the user's intention. This led to a short conversation which added no value to the question/answer, but cleared up my confusion. It could have been avoided with more precise wording, or with a simple emoji.

Comment: Additionally, many people use emoticons (e.g., :-) ) without issue. Emoji provide the same value in fewer bytes.

Comment: Emoticons render on most systems. They scale well.This isn't always true of emoji

Comment: Related: [Are we allowed to use emojis in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375834/335251), [Can/should emojis be disabled across SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323379/335251), [Do we have a policy on smileys? :)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172143/335251)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I would consider it noise in context. It adds little to the post, and is no different from indiscriminate, superfluous formatting.

*Not* to mention that emoji hardly render in a consistent way, so another user might see a series of boxes. There might also be some ambiguity in interpretation, and/or difficulty in reading it for some.

I'd say this is something I would strongly discourage, except when the emoji is an essential part of the question (and even then, some babysitting is needed).

Comment: Examples of the valid use of emoji: [How do these icons work: ✅️?](https://superuser.com/q/1173773), [Why are emoji characters like ‍‍‍ treated so strangely in Swift strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43618487). Other than that, I'm not sure site such as [pets.se]  deserves a post with emoji ...

Comment: In addition to not rendering at all for some people, they're just plain illegible to others without zooming way the heck in just to see the tiny pictures.  I don't want people to use emojis for essential content (if they use pictures instead of words) because they are not accessible.  At the very least, there'd need to be tooltips, but that doesn't help on touch screens.

Answer (score 10):

Well, the only place where I need to use an emoji is to coax users to accept and upvote answers that they found helpful instead of typing "thanks" and moving on.

> Don't write thanks in the comments. Instead, click the accept button (the tick ✅️ button) and upvote it (the  button) as a token of gratitude. This lets everyone know that the problem is solved.

Of course, I actually have to put the emoji because I've seen a few newbs who ask "Where are the upvote and accept buttons? I can't find them!".

And of course, the most bloodboiling newbie response, "*What does a tick symbol look like?*".

Comment: Well, every American I know calls that symbol a _checkmark_.

Comment: Haha that's exactly the point @JeffreyBosboom . We in India and probably even in UK call it a "tick".

Comment: @Unitato my thoughts exactly - not everyone knows what it is.

Comment: I prefer textual Unicode symbols: upvote (∧), accept (✓).

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where I see emojis are useful. For example, in Software Recommendation there is a [feature request to have checkbox](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2771/6389). Or when the conversation seems to be heated, an emoji can reduce the heat but still convey the necessary information.

<sup>If you use Windows, you can use AutoHotKey and add emojis via Markdown with [this script](https://github.com/alexmick/emoji-to-ahk/blob/master/custom_short_names.py).</sup>

Answer (score -3):

The emoji do, or did, serve a purpose in text conversation. You don't hear inflection nor see physical clues as to the intent of the words... I'm guilty of using  smiley faces because I never know when my sarcasm has gone over the endurance of people... A form of apology in advance?

Comment: What about here though? One would expect posts to be written with a reasonably formal tone. Texting on the other hand is informal. You can also assume emoji work on most modern phones. Not true of many browsers on desktop

Comment: You have good point. It's ato write erudite

Comment: This might pass in chat or comments, but NOT in posts.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I still haven't seen Emojis used much even in chat lol.

Comment: Yep I agree - in chat, but not posts. @ShaWizDowArd