# Do we have a policy on smileys? :)

Tags: support, etiquette, emoji

I hate smileys :D I know, that sounds strange from a 16-year old ^^ but I feel like smileys are lowering the professionalism of the network :(

I would ♥ to edit all posts with smileys, but fortunately I can keep myself under control O:)

But I still wonder: do we have a policy on the use of smileys?

---

<sup>Related: [Stack Overflow should have smileys and friend groups](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129038/205264) and especially [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129087/205264) answer.</sup>

<sup>[Useful smileys](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/197444/76821) are an exception of course.</sup>

Comment: Smileys are noise ;)

Comment: That second link is just a picture of how @Won't actually sees the world

Comment: Burn them! Burn them all with Fire! XD :)

Comment: Indeed, [that sounds strange from a 16-year old](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tAj3j.png).

Comment: If emoticons are to be banned, so should ♥s.

Comment: @Oded all emoticons in my question are meant to illustrate my hate. The ♥ is an example of that as well, yes.

Comment: So I've not caught you in an inconsistency. My plan has been foiled!

Comment: `:(` Am I the only one around here who likes emoticons? (I agree though that they should not be used in questions or answers).

Comment: I swear your profile had 21 as your age a few days ago, what are you up to? :o[)

Comment: I'm innocent! Really, I never changed my birthday on SE (in real life neither, by the way)

Comment: I didn't say in my previous comment, but it was either that or my own age playing tricks with my memory, I'll have to acknowledge the latter, upS!

Comment: @brasofilo: You seem to have mistaken him for me.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, five more years and Camil will be Unicorning the whole Stack.

Comment: @Felix Welcome to meta.. This is where the irony begins (and hopefully ends..) :D:D:D:D:D:D:D:D oh, and have a ★.

Comment: Stack Overflow for Teams has [reactions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391723/4751173) which are a kind of smiley as well (but not in the content of the post, it's more like a publicly visible vote).

Comment: Related: [Do we want emojis in posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299922/335251), [Are we allowed to use emojis in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375834/335251), [Can/should emojis be disabled across SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323379/335251)

Comment: "I hate smileys" And why this post is ful of exactly this smileys?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In questions and answers, [smileys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smiley) (and by extension, emojis) are almost always noise that detract from the core content, unless the question is about rendering, displaying or interacting with smileys.

Like most other minor forms of noise, feel free to remove them whenever you come across them. That said, I wouldn't edit just for a smiley alone.

As always, make sure your edits fix all the issues you can see, not just the trivial ones. (Particularly whilst your edits have to be reviewed.)

Comment: In questions and answers, yes I'd agree. Personally I don't have a problem with them in comments though; they seem more appropriate there. :o)

Comment: And I can't edit comments :'(

Comment: Would you rather [have a banana](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170699/bananas-in-comments), @Camil?

Comment: @Arjan [bananas](http://i3.asn.im/Awesome-banana-sculpture-_t77w.jpg) [are](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-DfWhqw5_C5c/TylazAUyqvI/AAAAAAAAAv0/JPUPZMhDNBw/s1600/Awesome%2Bbanana%2Bart.jpg) [awesome](http://craphound.com/images/bananashipmodel3.jpg)!

Comment: @JonW. I think all emoticons should be barred. Some people use :) not as simile/happy but as a smart-alec-smirk, a silent flame of i've made you look silly with this comment. Note emoticon included for clarity nor cos I use them

Answer (score 1):

Although I can understand the ‘unprofessionalism’ thought, when we’re essentially scrutinizing someone’s work, it can ease tension or notes of hostility with a smiley or two :) (in comments, not on a post)

Comment: If you venture into the non-posts worlds, also better mention chat, where it's even encouraged to use smileys when joking, and even when just chatting. :)