# Are we allowed to use emojis in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, emoji

I was wondering if we are allowed to use emojis (not excessively of course) in the **comments** to a post. This came to my mind when writing:

> I don’t know if we are referring to the same restrictions since every section has the word “restriction” . [...]

Initially I wrote:

> I don’t know if we are referring to the same restrictions since every section has the word “restriction”. [...]

But this feels colder to me and the laughing emoji makes the comment more friendly.

Keep in mind that I'm not recommending their use, I just think that in some particular cases where we see that the post owner is stuck with the question, a touch of friendliness could help with the resolution.

Comment: Why not? I have seen at least 30 comments with emoticons.

Comment: [Related discussion about emoji in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299922/do-we-want-emojis-in-posts).

Comment:      ➖     ➖  ©️ ️ 

Comment: I’ve seen them too but for me still feels informal to put emojis and since this is a pretty serious community before I start to put emojis in comments I wanted to confirm here

Comment: Okay, I definitely see that   ©️ ️ , thank you all! Hahaha

Comment: NO EMOJIS. WORDS. SAY WHAT YOU MEAN. (Am I yelling? YES I AM YELLING.) (Don't yell. Unless it is to say NO EMOJIS.)

Comment: Related: [Can/should emojis be disabled across SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323379/335251), [Do we have a policy on smileys? :)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172143/335251)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's allowed, or at least there is no rule I know of that says otherwise.

These days emojis are an integral part of our life and are part of every mobile device keyboard. They became part of the language.

So it's fine to use them in comments, to a limit of course, to express yourself better.

Comment: Emphasis on that final line– if you use emojis, make sure it really does help you express yourself _better_ and _clearer_, and not worse.

Answer (score 3):

Comments are temporary, and so their quality standards are much more relaxed than for posts (questions and answers) which are intended to form a more permanent record.

Nevertheless, I would avoid using them in comments too, lest that habit accidentally leads to including them in a post, creating extra work for our curators to remove them.

Comment: Pretty much how I feel. Can you use emojis in comments? Sure. *Should* you use emojis in comments? That's up to you, but I personally wouldn't in most cases (except perhaps to clearly indicate a joking tone in a comment that could be mistaken as being serious).