# Emoticons for Stack Exchange chat

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

Any ideas why there's no pictorial representation of facial expression (emoticon) in Stack Exchange chat? I'm just wondering.

I believe it's so cute to have this feature. :)

Comment: Just for reference [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/636/should-smilies-be-turned-into-images-in-questions-and-answers) was a feature-request on the posts....

Comment: from there, pinouchon's comment explains it.. thanks for the link @rene :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What benefit would there be other than it being "cute"?

Anyway what's stopping you doing it the traditional way ;)

Comment: Doing it the traditional way means people don't get to see loads of annoying yellow splodges everywhere, or bouncing distracting little animated annoying things.

Comment: Okay. Then I guess this discussion may answer to those who are curious too about it (think I'm the only one).